# WebAPI controller with IQueryable<T> throws "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, indexing, entity-framework-5, iqueryable

I'm fetching the data with OData syntax:
http://server.com/api/users?$skip=20&$top=10

I'm trying to add index to every fetched entity in my Web API Controller.
Every time I'm getting the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[WebPortal.Models.UserDto]
>   Select[UserInDatabase,UserDto](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[DataContext.UserInDatabase],
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[DataContext.Media,System.Int32,WebPortal.Models.UserDto]])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression.","ExceptionType":"System.NotSupportedException"

As I understand I couldn't use Select(u, index)=> selector while working with Entity Framework context (works fine for in memory collection). Unfortunately I'm using it to expose my collection via OData + QueryableAttribute:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<UserDto> Get()
    {
        return _repository.Users
                .Select((u, i) => new UserDto
                    {
                        Index = i,
                        Name = u.Name,
                        Age = u.Age
                    })
                .AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

How can I modify fetch process to continue to use OData syntax and have ability to return entities with index to requesting side?

my entities:

```
public class UserInDatabase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class UserDto
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
return _repository.Users
```

to

```
return _repository.Users.AsEnumerable()
```

This should force the query to execute before projecting onto your DTO.

Comment: unfortunately this is not the case because the query fetches all the data from the database BEFORE applying a filter. I have there thousands of rows. This is the exact reason why I'm introducing a pagination.

Comment: Do your pagination/filtering (Skip/Take) code *before* AsEnumerable().  Your Index will have to take how many rows you skipped into account as well (it's going to start at 0 regardless of how many you skipped).